# Unable to send FCM from postman

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to send push notifications from postman to my android app.I have added everything but it is showing error in response like below:

```
Error=MissingRegistration
```

This is how I am sending request:

[image]

In RAW json I am sending like this:

```
{
"to": "cLW-FpeVz5E:APA91bE2LsRdOe36gV0opaizoGKgZwuLEWP5O4JP6iU8kBcuqznAG4ztIlmiis6AyjFpANeBEta_IzRTkgJbGcI7_w_WbwZD0aZxI1u9orXFxls7211xSuuZPPlxCkejvOw_uUEA8vgv",

"notification": {

    "body": "Hello",
    "title": "This is test message."
  }
}
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly tried reproducing your issue and was able to.
Try changing your `Content-Type Header` from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to `application/json`
This fixed it when I tried.

Comment: Ohhh, that was silly thanks bro for pointing it out now its working fine after making changes.